# Clear form input field values after submitting in react js with ant-design

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro

I was created a registration page using react. There I have used this following registration form. https://ant.design/components/form. All the validation were handled properly and after successful attempt user can register to the system. Only problem I have faced is, unable to clear the form input field values after the submission.

I have implemented a method to clear the form field values to null. But it was not working. And I tried out previous similar questions in stackoverflow, but still couldn't get a workable one for me. Reason for that may be since I am using the ant design template.

```
this.setState({
        confirmDirty: false,
        autoCompleteResult: [],
        userName: '',
        email: '',
        experience: [],
        password: ''
})
```

Above code is to clear the input values. But it was not working and the all the form input fields values remained save. Below is the part of the registration form code.

```
class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
    autoCompleteResult: [],
    userName: '',
    email: '',
    experience: [],
    password: ''
};
//below form is inside the render method and return 
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
  <FormItem
    {...formItemLayout}
    label="E-mail"
  >
  {getFieldDecorator('email', {
     rules: [{
        type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
     }, {
        required: true, message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
     }],
     })(
        <Input />
     )}
  </FormItem>
</Form>
  handleSubmit = (e) => {
      e.preventDefault();
      this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
        if (!err) {
          //submission done
          //then execute the above code which I mentioned previously in the question, to reset the input fields value

        }
      });
  }
  }
```

Where I could get wrong and how can I resolve this?

Comment: Please share complete component code to understand your issue better

Comment: Please share the code which is using this state to clear fields.

Comment: Updated the question with more code. @HemadriDasari

Answer (score 26, accepted):

We can clear the form data using the `resetFields` function present in form props given by the ant design [library](https://ant.design/components/form/).

After the form is submitted successfully, use `this.props.form.resetFields()` to clear the data in the form.

Code:

```js
const { Form, Input, Tooltip, Icon, Cascader, Select, Row, Col, Checkbox, Button, AutoComplete, } = antd;

const { Option } = Select;
const AutoCompleteOption = AutoComplete.Option;

class RegistrationForm extends React.Component {
  state = {
    confirmDirty: false,
    autoCompleteResult: [],
  };

  handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.props.form.validateFieldsAndScroll((err, values) => {
      if (!err) {
        console.log('Received values of form: ', values);
      }
    });
  }

  handleConfirmBlur = (e) => {
    const value = e.target.value;
    this.setState({ confirmDirty: this.state.confirmDirty || !!value });
  }

  render() {
    const { getFieldDecorator } = this.props.form;
    const { autoCompleteResult } = this.state;

    const formItemLayout = {
      labelCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 8 },
      },
      wrapperCol: {
        xs: { span: 24 },
        sm: { span: 16 },
      },
    };
    const tailFormItemLayout = {
      wrapperCol: {
        xs: {
          span: 24,
          offset: 0,
        },
        sm: {
          span: 16,
          offset: 8,
        },
      },
    };

    return (
      <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <Form.Item
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="E-mail"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('email', {
            rules: [{
              type: 'email', message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
            }, {
              required: true, message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
            }],
          })(
            <Input />
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item
          {...formItemLayout}
          label="Password"
        >
          {getFieldDecorator('password', {
            rules: [{
              required: true, message: 'Please input your password!',
            }, {
              validator: this.validateToNextPassword,
            }],
          })(
            <Input type="password" />
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...tailFormItemLayout}>
          {getFieldDecorator('agreement', {
            valuePropName: 'checked',
          })(
            <Checkbox>I have read the <a href="">agreement</a></Checkbox>
          )}
        </Form.Item>
        <Form.Item {...tailFormItemLayout}>
          <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">Register</Button>
        </Form.Item>

        <Form.Item {...tailFormItemLayout}>
          <Button onClick={e => {
this.props.form.resetFields()
                          }} >Clear</Button>
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
    );
  }
}

const WrappedRegistrationForm = Form.create()(RegistrationForm);

ReactDOM.render(<WrappedRegistrationForm />, mountNode);
```

[Live Demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/WLOrmq?editors=0010)

Hope it helps :)

Comment: will it clear the initialValue={} attributes in the form elements also?

Answer (score 36):

In a function component, you can very easily get access to the form using the `Form.useForm` hook. The value returned by this hook should be passed as the `form` property of the `Form` component. Then you can just call `resetFields` on the form in whatever callback you want to clear the form. This example will clear the form when it is submitted:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Form, Input } from 'antd';

export default function MyFormComponent() {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();

  const submitForm = ({ name, favoriteColor }) => {
    console.log(name, favoriteColor);
    form.resetFields();
  };

  return (
    <Form
      form={form}
      labelCol={{ span: 6 }}
      wrapperCol={{ span: 12 }}
      onFinish={submitForm}
    >
      <Form.Item name="name" label="What is your name?">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item name="favoriteColor" label="What is your favorite color?">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>
      <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 6, span: 12 }}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
}
```

This only works in antd 4.x and later. Forms seem to have been much more difficult to work with in earlier versions.

Comment: could you please help on resetting value for Radio.Group on form.resetFields(); call. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61720143/reset-radio-group-values-onsubmit-click-for-antd-library

Comment: should be useFormInstance().resetFields no?

Comment: @SimoneMasiero useFormInstance is used differently (and I think didn't exist yet when I wrote this answer). It would be useful to have another answer showing how to use it though.

Answer (score 23):

`form.resetFields()` will reset all form fields.

To reset a particular form field `form.resetFields([formItemName])`

[FormInstance](https://ant.design/components/form/#FormInstance)

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Form, Input } from "antd";

const myComp = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [val, setVal] = useState("");

  const handleCancel = () => {
    form.resetFields();    //reset form
  };

  const handleOk = async (e) => {
      form.resetFields();    //reset form
  };

  const handelChange = async (e) => {
      setVal(e.target.value);
      if(val.length > 10) {
        form.resetFields(["textField"]); //reset particular field
      }
  };

  return (
      <Form
        form={form}
        name="dynamic_ruleEdit"
        onFinish={handleOk}
      >
        <Form.Item
          name="textField"
          label="Enter your details"
          rules={[
            {
              message: "Enter details",
              required: true,
            },
          ]}
        >
          <Input
            value={val}
            placeholder="Enter details"
            onChange={handelChange}
          />
        </Form.Item>
      </Form>
  );
}
export default myComp;
```

Comment: Make sure  form={form} is added in the form component. I was missing this. Thank you

Answer (score 6):

Very Simple Solution:
Just put this line in the functional component

`const [form] = Form.useForm();`

```
<Form
            form={form}
            name="normal_login"
            className="login-form"
            initialValues={{
            remember: true,
            }}
/>
```

After than call the `form` into `onFinish()` function.

```
const onFinish=(values)=>{
     
      form.resetFields();
      let array1=[];
      if(Array.isArray(array1)){
        array1=values;
        localStorage.setItem(`${id}`,JSON.stringify({id,...array1}));
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

1. the simplest way to reset the entire form you use resetForm().

```
form.resetFields()
```

2. For those inputs you want to change the default value, you can specify it using setFieldsValue().

```
...
onChange={() => form.setFieldsValue({ name: '' })}
...
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new Button and set the onclick().
2. Then call this.props.form.resetFields() in onclick of the button
   which you created above.
3. For this whole you need to export your component as export default
   Form.create()(YourComponent);