# Reset Radio.Group values onSubmit click for antd library

Tags: reactjs, antd, ant-design-pro

I am using ant-design library. There is `useForm()` hook to reset values.

All values are being reset to original values but not for Radio.Group.

How do I reset my radio button state to `priority` value from State?

```
  const [priority, setPriority] = useState(2);
 const [form] = Form.useForm();

const onSubmit = (values) => {
    console.log('Received values of form: ', values);

    form.resetFields();
  }

<Form
          form={form}
          labelCol={{ span: 4 }}
          wrapperCol={{ span: 14 }}
          layout="horizontal"
          initialValues={{ size: "large" }}
          size={"large"}
          onFinish={onSubmit}
        >
          <Form.Item
            name="title"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Title is required!' }]}
            label="Title">
            <Input placeholder="Title" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item
            name="content"
            rules={[{ required: true, message: 'Content is required!' }]}
            label="Content">
            <Input.TextArea placeholder="Content" />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item label="Switch" name="switch">
            <Switch />
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item name="priority" label="Radio.Button">
            <Radio.Group defaultValue={priority}
              onChange={onPriorityChange}>
              <Radio.Button value={2}>High</Radio.Button>
              <Radio.Button value={1}>Medium</Radio.Button>
              <Radio.Button value={0}>Low</Radio.Button>
            </Radio.Group>
          </Form.Item>
          <Form.Item>
            <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
              Submit
        </Button>
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
```

Comment: Can't you just call your `onPriorityChange` ? Or `setPriority(2)` (Since you are initialising it to `2`) ?

Comment: What value should it reset to... 2?

Comment: @QuentinGrisel yeah for some reason that's not working too

Comment: @chandan_kr_jha yes I want it to be value 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added priority to the initialValues and it worked.

Refer this.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-agnesi-9vp4x?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Nope, there is no radio selected after the submit

Comment: I want to set that when submit is clicked. its not resetting it to high after you click submit in this example

Comment: The sandbox is almost correct, just change use this `initialValues={{ size: "large", priority:2 }}` and it works ;) (I added `:2` to precise the desired value)

Comment: nice. I forgot to save I think.

Comment: if you guys can help with this question please? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61723295/antd-library-how-to-approach-when-trying-to-render-an-image